# How to use Kerberos libraries in Python?

Tags: python, python-requests, kerberos

I am trying to use some Python library to automatically login to a Kerberos account. For example, I found [requests_kerberos](https://github.com/requests/requests-kerberos), and my code is:

```
import requests
from requests_kerberos import HTTPKerberosAuth, REQUIRED
r = requests.get("https://cas.id.ubc.ca/ubc-cas/login", auth=HTTPKerberosAuth())
```

However, even before I have a chance to input my username and password, the third line raises `requests_kerberos.exceptions.MutualAuthenticationError: Unable to authenticate <Response [200]>`

Is there something wrong? Does UBC CWL support logging in by Kerberos?

Answer (score 2):

You can disable the mutual authentication as indicated here:
https://github.com/requests/requests-kerberos

This could work:

```
import requests
from requests_kerberos import HTTPKerberosAuth, REQUIRED, OPTIONAL, DISABLED
r = requests.get("https://cas.id.ubc.ca/ubc-cas/login", auth=HTTPKerberosAuth(mutual_authentication=OPTIONAL))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if my understanding is goob but finally you want to connect to UBC services ?
Because I found some Github project to do that:

- https://github.com/kboone/pyUBC (Python)
- All: https://github.com/search?l=&q=ubc.ca+cwl+language%3APython&type=Code