# requests-kerberos returns "unable to authenticate <Response 200>"

Tags: ansible, kerberos

I have encountered a strange error on the infrastructure I'm managing.

```
UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "kerberos: Unable to authenticate <Response [200]>",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

The error above appears only when pinging/deploying a playbook to one particular server, around 33% of the time, but it stops me from running longer Ansible playbooks - it fails between tasks.

I have checked WinRM settings, TLS and cryptography registry keys, domain controller and the server have constant connection and the time on them is synced. Everything looks fine and is the same as on a mirrored server, on which this error doesn't appear.

I think the issue lays somewhere between my machine and the target server, or between target server and domain controller, but I ran out of ideas on how to locate the issue.

Comment: Related, although not answering the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50081793/how-to-use-kerberos-libraries-in-python. It seems like the mutual authentication could be the issue. Now, I did not find a simple and obvious way to configure that when used via Ansible